How to package and maintain helm charts for both open and closed beta?
I manage some Kubernetes CRDs and package them in Helm Charts for managing the different versions. Currently we only have one Helm Chart version that we deploy to production which is v1.0.0 and any bugfixes or updates we just patch it. v1.0.0 is currently in open beta.
However, after working on a new feature for version 2.0.0 that has breaking changes to the existing content of v1.0.0 (e.g. new CRDs, modifying/deleting existing CRDs in v1.0.0), I have come to a point where I need to maintain both open and closed beta versions of the latest package version. This is to ensure that v2.0.0 is in closed beta and doesn't get shown to users yet while we have v1.0.0 still available to edit in case users report issues with it.
My question is how can we package the helm charts to maintain both open and closed beta versions? Do we need to make 2 separate helm charts for open and closed beta (aka 2 different helm directories, see the example diagram below)? Or does helm have a way of doing what we want (e.g. directly within Chart.yaml, excluding certain files from helm package for specific versions, etc)?
Thanks
Example of maintaining 2 different helm charts for each version:
<root directory>
|
---my product
   |
   ---v1.0.0
      |
      ---Chart.yaml, values.yaml, Chart.lock, CRDs for v1 etc
   |
   ---v2.0.0
      ---Chart.yaml, values.yaml, Chart.lock, CRDs for v2 etc


The Go text/template language does most things you'd expect a programming language to, including conditionals, and you could wrap the entire content of individual files in {{ if }}...{{ end }} blocks.  If this was me I'd probably manage the chart on two separate branches of my source repository.

Correct me if I'm wrong in my understanding, you want to merge the 2 versions into one so that you don't duplicate the code but still be able to select which flavor to install, right?
If that's the case you could do what David mentioned earlier, use IF to change the mode of installation depending on a Values value. Would that work for you?
